# Add headers in requests in firefox using selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, firefox

We are trying to add a key value pair in the requests header in the **firefox** browser using **selenium**. Here is the add-on that we are using:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/modify-header-value/

We have installed the add-on using:

```
wd.install_addon(os.path.join(os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                                               "lib", "modify_header_value-0.1.8.xpi"))
```

Here is the firefox preference that we are setting for the webdriver:

```
ff_prof = FirefoxProfile(profile_directory=kwargs.get('user_data_dir'))
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.count", 1)
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.action0", "Add")
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.name0", "header_name")  # Set here the name of the header
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.value0", "header_value")  # Set here the value of the header
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.headers.enabled0", True)
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.config.active", True)
ff_prof.set_preference("modifyheaders.config.alwaysOn", True)
```

But this solution doesn't seem to be working.
Is there any alternative that we can do, like set this custom header from the firefox option itself? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Firefox version: **Mozilla Firefox 91.13.0esr**. We are obliged to this version for now.